# how can I programatically transition between those 2 window layouts?

Tags: window, window-splitting

I am trying to implement this window transition

```
a/             b/     
---------      -------------
| 1 | 2 |      |   | 1 | 2 |
---------  ->  | 0 |-------|
| 3 | 4 |      |   | 3 | 4 |
---------      -------------
```

More precisely, I'm trying to implement something similar to neotree, that opens in some sort of sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `display-buffer-in-side-window` you get almost what you are asking for.
The windows will not be numbered in the way you want them but the layout is exactly as you requested.

I demonstrate it in the following with the scratch buffer in window 0 of your window-layout:

```el
(display-buffer "*scratch*" '(display-buffer-in-side-window (side . left)))
```

Note that you can switch between two window configuration with the help of `current-window-configuration` and `set-window-configuration`.